# Shift values in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shift

I have a data frame :

```
dt <- read.table(text = "
0 344 34 0 0
0 350 16 0 0
0 366 11 0 0
0 376 8  0 0
0 380 28 0 0
0 397 55 0 0
0 398 45 0 0  
0 400 19 0 0 
0 402 30 0 0")
```

I want to shift randomly 1/3 of rows to the right by one column, to obtain for example:

```
dt1 <- read.table(text = "
0 344 34 0 0
0 350 16 0 0
0 0 366 11 0 
0 376 8  0 0
0 0 380 28 0 
0 0 397 55 0
0 398 45 0 0  
0 400 19 0 0 
0 402 30 0 0")
```

Is it possible to have a parameter to choose the number of shifts? If I want to shift by two, three or four columns instead of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions, which can be wrapped up as a function if you like.

The philosophy of the first solution is to transpose your dataset and use the rows as columns so you can use `mutate_at` (your randomly selected rows) and then transpose again:

```
dt <- read.table(text = "
0 344 34 0 0
0 350 16 0 0
0 366 11 0 0
0 376 8  0 0
0 380 28 0 0
0 397 55 0 0
0 398 45 0 0  
0 400 19 0 0 
0 402 30 0 0")

library(tidyverse)

# for reproducibility
set.seed(4)

# pick number of rows to shift
num_rows = round(1/3 * nrow(dt))

# sample position of those rows
rows = sample(1:nrow(dt), num_rows)

# specify number of shifts
num_shifts = 2


t(dt) %>%                           # transpose dataset
  data.frame() %>%                  # update to data frame
  mutate_at(rows, ~lag(., num_shifts, default = 0L)) %>%  # use the selected row positions and the selected number of shifts to apply this function
  t() %>%                           # transapose data again
  data.frame(., row.names = NULL)   # update to dataframe

#   X1  X2 X3  X4 X5
# 1  0   0  0 344 34
# 2  0 350 16   0  0
# 3  0   0  0 366 11
# 4  0 376  8   0  0
# 5  0 380 28   0  0
# 6  0   0  0 397 55
# 7  0 398 45   0  0
# 8  0 400 19   0  0
# 9  0 402 30   0  0
```

And an alternative approach, without transposing, but working with rows using `map2`:

```
dt %>%
  group_by(id = row_number()) %>%   # group by row id
  nest() %>%                        # nest data
  mutate(d = map2(id, data, ~if(.x %in% rows) lag(.y, num_shifts, default = 0L) else .y)) %>%  # apply shift to selected row positions/ids
  unnest(d) %>%                     # unnest data
  select(-id, -data)                # remove unnecessary columns

# # A tibble: 9 x 5
#      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     0     0     0   344    34
# 2     0   350    16     0     0
# 3     0     0     0   366    11
# 4     0   376     8     0     0
# 5     0   380    28     0     0
# 6     0     0     0   397    55
# 7     0   398    45     0     0
# 8     0   400    19     0     0
# 9     0   402    30     0     0
```